# Order By Month, then Year when MonthYear is a string SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, ssms

```
declare @ActivityYearStart int = 2014
declare @ActivityYear2 int = (@ActivityYearStart + 2)
declare @ActivityYearEnd int = 2015
declare @ActivityYearM1 int = (@ActivityYearEnd - 1)
declare @ActivityMonth int = 1
declare @ActivityMonth1 int = 3

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME((CONVERT(varchar(5), ActivityMonth) + '-' 
                + CONVERT(varchar(5), ActivityYear))) As MonthYear
            FROM Forecast
            WHERE((ActivityYear = @ActivityYearStart)
              AND (ActivityMonth between  @ActivityMonth and 12))
              OR ((ActivityYear between @ActivityYear2 and @ActivityYearM1)
              AND (ActivityMonth between 1 and 12))
              OR ((ActivityYear = @ActivityYearEnd) 
              AND (ActivityMonth between 1 and @ActivityMonth1))
                     AND Category = 'Forecast'
           Group By Category, ID, ActivityMonth, ActivityYear
           Order By SUBSTRING(MonthYear, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(MonthYear, 2, 4)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = '  
    SELECT Category, ID, ' + @cols + ' FROM
             (
                SELECT Category, ID, (CONVERT(varchar(5), ActivityMonth) + ''-'' 
                + CONVERT(varchar(5), ActivityYear)) As MonthYear, HoursCharged
                FROM Forecast    
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
                Sum(HoursCharged)
                for MonthYear in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Since `MonthYear` is a concatenated string of Activity Month and Activity year - went from rows to columns. I would like to order by the Month Year but, it is now a string and orders by string values rather than int values. How would I be able to break it up to `Order By SUBSTRING(MonthYear, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(MonthYear, 2, 4)`.

But I get the error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   Invalid column name 'MonthYear'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   Invalid column name 'MonthYear'.
>
> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Can you take out "Distinct"?   You shouldn't need it since you include ActivityMonth and ActivityYear in the GROUP BY.

Comment: If I take out distinct I get the same error with the order by clause. If I remove the order by statement, without distinct I get the error: Msg 1056, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Comment: Ok, why are you grouping by Category and ID?  You don't have either in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your @cols declaration with this:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME((CONVERT(varchar(5), ActivityMonth) + '-' 
                + CONVERT(varchar(5), ActivityYear))) As MonthYear
            FROM Forecast
            WHERE((ActivityYear = @ActivityYearStart)
              AND (ActivityMonth between  @ActivityMonth and 12))
              OR ((ActivityYear between @ActivityYear2 and @ActivityYearM1)
              AND (ActivityMonth between 1 and 12))
              OR ((ActivityYear = @ActivityYearEnd) 
              AND (ActivityMonth between 1 and @ActivityMonth1))
                     AND Category = 'Forecast'
           Group By ActivityMonth, ActivityYear
           Order By ActivityYear, ActivityMonth
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```